# Pandas: change the index to become a column

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas, how do I change the index to become a column like in my example tables below?

I've tried variations of `df.reset_index()` but to no avail.

df

```
                    0         1         2
       Year      Tractors    Barns    Bales
       1960         1         10       1000
       1961         2         11       1100
       1962         3         12       1200
```

df_new

```
                    Year      Tractors    Barns    Bales
        0           1960         1         10       1000
        1           1961         2         11       1100
        2           1962         3         12       1200
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use set columns from first row of dataframe with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename`:

```
print df
            0     1     2
Year Tractors Barns Bales
1960        1    10  1000
1961        2    11  1100
1962        3    12  1200

print df.iloc[0]
1    Tractors
2       Barns
3       Bales
Name: Year, dtype: object

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None

df = df[1:].reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Year'})
print df
   Year Tractors Barns Bales
0  1960        1    10  1000
1  1961        2    11  1100
2  1962        3    12  1200
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, @jezrael. Just tried that and got back `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'`

Comment: Additionally, how can I make `Year` a column instead of an index?

Comment: What is `print df.columns`?

Comment: `print df.columns` = `Int64Index([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,
            ...
            1335, 1336, 1337, 1338, 1339, 1340, 1341, 1342, 1343, 1344],
           dtype='int64', length=1345)`


Working with a dataframe that has 1345 distinct columns

Comment: Brilliant, @jezrael! Outcome is just what I was hoping for!

Can you please explain a bit more what the following code is doing?
`df.index.name = None`
`df.columns.name = None`

Thanks!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have been typing `df.reset_index()` and observing the output, but `df` remains unchanged. If you type:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

you will probably get the result you want.

P.S. The integers on top of your column names -- did you put those there for the question, or are they from a set of hierarchically-indexed columns? If you need to get rid of the integers in `df`, you can type:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, Bill! The numbers are from a set of hierarchically-indexed columns. @jezrael's solution worked perfectly.